# How do I convert a textField`s String to a Double in xCode with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am making a very simple beginner project where I receive the data from a textField and store it in a Double var. I have tried the .toDouble() but it doesn´t seem to exist. Any help please?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply put the string in as a parameter when creating a double!

`let double = Double(textView.text!)`

Comment: @RMenke it depends on the Xcode version but Xcode7 it is ok

Comment: @LeoDabus You are right, but it returns an optional. That is why I don't use it. My Bad :)

Comment: @RMenke  just add the nil coalescing operator ?? 0

Answer (score 5):

Add the following extension and use `.toDouble()`

```
extension String {
func toDouble() -> Double? {
    return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
 }
}
```

Like

```
var someString = “30.23"
var someDouble = someString.toDouble()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension String {
    var doubleValue: Double {
        return Double(self) ?? 0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let inputString = "32.1"
let myDouble = inputString.doubleValue   // 32.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let doubleValue = Double(textView.text!) {

} else {
    print("Not a valid number: \(textView.text!)")
}
```